# Can I color-calibrate a Dell U2413 wide-gamut monitor under Linux?

Tags: monitors, color-management

If I get a Dell U2413 wide-gamut monitor to use with Fedora for photography, will I be able to use it properly? I've got a [ColorHug](http://www.hughski.com/), and I [see](http://www.hughski.com/downloads/colorhug/ccmx/) that there's a U2410 [ccmx profile](http://www.hughski.com/calibrate.html); will that get me in a reasonable enough ballpark? Or should I just go with the standard-gamut U2412M (for half the price)?

I'd prefer the wider-gamut color in the ideal world, of course, but I'd prefer perfectly-working 8-bit sRGB to miscalibrated wide-gamut.

(PS: Linux only; no dual-boot.)

Comment: I worked with a research group and the cluster for which a paper was published on how to do this very thing -- but for _very large displays_. So it might be in the "overkill" category. Nevertheless, I'm sure you'll find some interesting ideas here. [Cross-LUT Color Correction for Large Tiled Displays](http://people.cs.clemson.edu/~geist/keck/to_jk/t_rep_paper.pdf)

Comment: I think I'm missing something. I'm specifically looking to calibrate a wide-gamut monitor for daily use in Linux, whereas your paper covers color calibration for projectors (which are probably not wide gamut) using a specialized renderer. Maybe I'm just being dense; can you draw the connection to "how to do this very thing" more clearly for me?

Comment: The projectors were DLP with _varying_ gamuts and luminosities. So they solved a very general problem. I can't give you a better answer -- I only hoped you'd find something in the paper that would point you in the right direction re tools and well-known algorithms. I'm sorry if that wasted your time.

Comment: I don't mind the time — it's an interesting paper. I just don't think it really answers this question. :)

Answer (score 1):

I shouldn't be answering really, since my only experience with Colorimeters was an old Spyder2 and the results were so utterly horrible I decided to not follow this "religion" anymore. I'm happy with the factory colors my display gives me. ;)

In theory, it should work.

As for using it in Linux someone wrote a blog article about the process here: http://macprofilingandcalibration.blogspot.com/2013/06/display-calibration-and-profiling-in.html

As for wide-gamut there's an interview here where it is mentioned: https://banu.com/blog/41/interview-of-colorhug-maker-richard-hughes/

But in practice, who can say really? You have no real control over what kind of result you're going to get and whether you'll be happy with it. There's only one way to find out...

Maybe you should take this question to the colorhug users list, you could have more luck finding someone with that or similar gamut monitors there https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/colorhug-users

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely use a wide gamut colourspace on Linux, but you should think about what you actually want to achieve (aside from having the satisfaction of knowing your gamut is wide). Just because a colourspace is really wide doesn't mean those colours are going to then translate well to the other colourspaces you are going to deliver to.

The ccmx for the U2410 will probably get you within what you are looking for. I have a ColorHug and I've had good success with it on a variety of monitors.

As a conversion space, I use the [ACES](http://www.oscars.org/science-technology/sci-tech-projects/aces) colourspace, for for everyday work I just use whatever colourspace everyone (or everything, if the only other thing involved is a printer) is using. A good general-purpose colourspace is [REC709](http://www.color.org/rec709.xalter)